# How to create Compute Engine using Google Cloud public images in Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I am trying to create a VM in Terraform based on Deep Learning Image: Base m71 CUDA11.0 image included in Deep Learning On Linux from Public Image on Google Cloud. In this case what string should I put in the image key in HCL?

Answer (score 1):

To specify the boot image `Deep Learning Image: Base m71 CUDA11.0`, use the following `boot_disk` in your Terraform code:

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "default" {
  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "c0-deeplearning-common-cu110-v20210527-debian-10"
    }
```

To list the deep learning images:

```
gcloud compute images list \
--project deeplearning-platform-release \
--no-standard-images
```